# How to transform xml block?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, mode

I am new at XSL and I couldn't find anywhere like following case. I want to transform source.xml to target.xml. I have use mode "group" but it didn't work for me (probably I couldn't use it properly)

source.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<PersonBody>

    <Person>
        <D>Name</D>
        <D>Surname</D>
        <D>Id</D>
    </Person>

    <PersonValues>
        <D>Michael</D>
        <D>Jackson</D>
        <D>01</D>
    </PersonValues>

    <PersonValues>
        <D>James</D>
        <D>Bond</D>
        <D>007</D>
    </PersonValues>

    <PersonValues>
        <D>Kobe</D>
        <D>Bryant</D>
        <D>24</D>
    </PersonValues>

</PersonBody>
```

target.xml:

```
<PersonBody>
  <AllValues>
    <Name>
      <D>Michael</D>
      <D>James</D>
      <D>Kobe</D>
    </Name>
    <Surname>
      <D>Jackson</D>
      <D>Bond</D>
      <D>Bryant</D>
    </Surname>
    <Id>
      <D>01</D>
      <D>007</D>
      <D>24</D>
    </Id>
  </AllValues>
</PersonBody>
```

EDIT : I have asked another question because the output is changed.
You can find the other question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192234/how-to-transform-xml-to-requested-one)

Comment: Kindly let me know what you have tried?

Comment: The first `<D>` in `<Id>` is blank, but is that just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kColumnValue" match="PersonValues/*" 
           use="count(preceding-sibling::*)" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <AllValues>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person/*" />
      </AllValues>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person/*">
    <xsl:element name="{.}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kColumnValue', position() - 1)" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample XML, the result is:

```
<PersonBody>
  <AllValues>
    <Name>
      <D>Michael</D>
      <D>James</D>
      <D>Kobe</D>
    </Name>
    <Surname>
      <D>Jackson</D>
      <D>Bond</D>
      <D>Bryant</D>
    </Surname>
    <Id>
      <D>01</D>
      <D>007</D>
      <D>24</D>
    </Id>
  </AllValues>
</PersonBody>
```

Comment: Are you trying to substitute `<xsl:copy>` with `<xsl:element name="{.}">`?

Comment: @serhiy.h No, `<xsl:copy>` would not produce the correct result here. I used `<xsl:element name="{.}">` because that produces the correct result.

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe but the output is different than I gave. Sorry about that. I was trying to develop an xsl for requested output but no success. I will edit my question for output. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry. will open a new question. Thanks.